# Extending line segment to polygon edge using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, parallel-lines, extend

I am trying to extend line segments to the related parcel.  There is not an address field in the line segment but there is a year field.  The year field is what needs to be added to the parcel to conduct further analysis.
Is there a tool that allows you to extend a group of line segments to the nearest polygon based off of start or end points?  I also would like to have a threshold of X.
I've played around with the extend line tool.
Could just turn the vertices to start point for the line and then join spatially to the nearest polygon but I don't have confidence in this method.

Answer (score 2):

ArcMap has Extend Lines in the Editing Toolbox. A Standard or Advanced license is required. The Parcel Polygons might need to be converted to Lines and added to the  same feature class that you are extending.